# Do I need US, UK transit visas travelling Dubai-London-Dallas-Calgary as an Indian citizen?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas

Hi I'm Indian and planning to travel from Dubai, where I am a resident, to Calgary on British Airways (roundtrip) with two layovers: one at London Heathrow, and the other at Dallas. I have a Canadian visitor visa, but am confused with web search as some sites say that I will need transit visas for the UK and US, while others say that I don't. Do I need these visas also?

Comment: For completeness, is the itinerary booked as one ticket (one PNR)? Entering the full details of your trip and travel documents in IATA https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/ will give you a reliable answer. Unlike many other countries, the United States does not allow sterile transit, which means that for any stop in the US, you have to pass through Customs and Immigration. For UK see https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y

Comment: What site says you don't need a visa for the US?  Either that site is wrong or you are misinterpreting it.

Comment: You don't need a UK transit visa as you are exempt on the basis of your Canadian visa. You need a US visa as you need to clear passport control in the US amd enter the US. There is no airside transit in the US. There are links posted in the answer and other comments for you to confirm.

Comment: Be aware that in some consulates there can be a two-year wait to get a visa for the US.

Comment: If I transit through Frankfurt do I need transit visa? Dubai- Frankfurt -calgary

Answer (score 5):

According to [the UK government's Visa Check](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/no), you will not require a UK transit visa if you are on a connecting itinerary and can complete your transfer airside because you meet the first exception, "you have[...] a visa for Canada."

According to the [US Visa Wizard](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wizard.html), you will require a US visitor (B) or transit (C) visa for your connection in Dallas, as India is not part of the US Visa Waiver Program or any other visa-free arrangement with the US.

Answer (score 2):

You won't need a transit visa if you can complete your transfer at Heathrow without passing through border control (known as airside transit), according to the [UK Government's visa checking tool](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/no). This is because you already have a Canadian visitor visa.

You will need a visitor visa or a transit visa when you are transiting through the United States. [See the U.S. Government's visa checking tool.](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wizard.html) You can apply at the nearest U.S. embassy or consulate. If you don't already have the visa, make the appointment ASAP. Wait times can be long.

Important: Airlines can deny you boarding if they believe you don't have the right documentation. Keeping your itinerary on a single ticket (as opposed to separate tickets requiring self-transfers) shows airline employees that you are transiting instead of visiting the UK and the USA. [See the table in this article for more info about the differences between connecting flights and self-transfer flights.](https://connectingflights.info/what-is-an-airport-self-transfer/#:%7E:text=Self%20transfers%20are%20the%20complete,with%20airline%2Dprotected%20connecting%20flights.) If you are on self-transfer flights, airlines might ask for documentation showing that you can enter the UK or USA as a visitor instead of as a visitor in transit because they can't verify onward flights that aren't booked through their systems.